# Is there a definition or convention about the initial part of a plot?

Tags: graphing-functions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/w6mdjf4nVTA?t=132)

> Initially the gradient is positive and "fairly constant", but for it drops to zero at the peak, it then becomes negative for a period before returning to zero.

figure_1

[image]

assume the initial part is the time frame between the starting point, shown above, and somewhere shown below

figure_2

[image]

the gradients at these 2 points is close, compared to the one shown below.

[image]

although, the gradients in figure_1 and figure_2 are obviously different, which seems not to be "fairly constant". The earlier the initial part, the better.

So, there a definition or convention about the initial part of a plot?

Comment: The fact that the gradient is "fairly constant" here has nothing to do with it being towards the start of the plot.

Comment: @JackCrawford Does "being towards the start of the plot" mean the direction of the tangent line or something else?